# Make a clone of html element in _hyperscript

Tags: hyperscript

How to make a clone of html element in _hyperscript?

For example, I want to see a copy of a button after clicking on it. Something like:

```
<button _="on click put me after me">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the hyperscript to work for new nodes I currently do something like this:

```
<div id="test123">
   <div _="on click log 'Test' then put my outerHTML after me 
       _hyperscript.processNode(#test123)">Copy Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks! Looks like that there will be [changes](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/_hyperscript/issues/133) in _hyperscript that would automatically process new html nodes after adding them to DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
<button _='on click put my outerHTML after me'>Test</button>
```

However, only clicking the original button produces a copy this way.

Comment: It turned out, that you can convert element with [as](https://hyperscript.org/expressions/as/) expression, but still it gives same result as in your example:

`<button _="on click put me as HTML after me">Test</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as I wanted to have hyperscript on a newly made element from within hyperscript.
In my first attempts I used `append` upon stumbling over this post here and by chance searching in the hyperscript docs for `processNode` I found this entry in the [release notes](https://hyperscript.org/posts/2022-07-12-hyperscript-0.9.6-is-released/):

> Hyperscript in content added by the put command will be automatically initialized (no need to call _hyperscript.processNode() now!)

With that I used `put <something> into <container>` and it got perfectly initialized.

Maybe some others stumble upon this problem.